# Make a timer using sleep in python. How to account for computation time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, timer

I'm trying to make a simple timer which prints the time remaining every second.

```
for k in range(100):
    print(100-k)
    t.sleep(1)
#output
#100
#99
#98
#...
#1
```

However, this will take slightly longer than 100 seconds, because there will be a delay added when print() is used. For long periods, this is slightly noticeable. Is there a way to account for this, and accurately display the time every second? I know I could just `sleep(100)`, but this wouldn't let the time left be printed.

Comment: Well, `sleep` is also not perfectly accurate, so each time you're `sleep`ing a tiny bit more or a tiny bit less than a second.

Comment: Have you looked at time.perf_counter?

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
start_time=time.time()
for k in range(25):
    print(25-k)
    time.sleep(1)
print("it took  "+str(float(time.time()-start_time)*1000)+" Milliseconds")
```

the output with print is: `it took  26412.75382041931 Milliseconds`

the output without print : `it took  25053.035020828247 Milliseconds`

it should have been just 25000 milliseconds but it is not

printing will take time, even reading the code takes time
point is don't expect accurate timing with time.sleep() !!!

Comment: This only *measures* the time each interval takes, but doesn't shorten it so that they are one second long.

Comment: not supposed to shorten it, it is to show that time.sleep() does not work accurate !

Answer (score 1):

You can use `time.time()` to measure elapsed time.

```
import time
start_time = time.time()

for k in range(100):
    # k seconds SHOULD be elapsed at this point
    print(100 - k)
    slept_time = time.time() - start_time
    time.sleep(1 + k-slept_time)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `time.sleep` will never give you the accurate time for your timer, since the time it takes is the one second sleep time + printing time, you can use `threading.Timer` to get more accurate results. https://repl.it/Hwkt :

```
import threading, time

start_time=time.time()
def count_loop(counter):
  if counter <= 0: 
    print("it took  "+str(float(time.time()-start_time)*1000)+" Milliseconds")
    return

  threading.Timer(1.0, count_loop, args=[counter-1]).start()
  print(counter)      

count_loop(100)
```

This is still not accurate, but with only very minimum offset, only 45 ms. However, when using `time.sleep` from legendisback's example, there is apparently 81 ms delay. https://repl.it/HwlK